# Can't test my ionic app on device or emulator, it gives me" Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of """

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular12, ionic6

I'm using ionic 6 and angular 12, I'm testing my app on browser and its working ok, the problem is when I try to test it on emulator or phone. I am inspecting it on chrome and it gives me these errors and after the splash screen it gives a blank screen.

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. runtime.js
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. main.js
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. polyfills.js
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. vendor.js
```

This is my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Noz Terra</title>

 <base href="./">

  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/imgs/nozterra1.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />


</head>

<body>
  <app-root>
  </app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the index.html file generated in www folder when I compile(which I think is the root of the problem):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Noz Terra</title>

 <base href="./">

  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/imgs/nozterra1.png"/>

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>

<body>
  <app-root>
  </app-root>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="cordova.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change type="module" into type="text/javascript" and try again